# ASP.NET Core 8 MVC: Razor ValidationMessageFor is displaying title message instead of error message

Tags: validation, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

In my app I work with tests, and this next piece of code of my view is where user enters a test number:

```
@inject LocService SharedLocalizer

@{
    ...
    var testLevel_hint = SharedLocalizer.GetString("Test.TestLevel.Hint");
}

...

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(o => o.TestLevel)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(o => o.TestLevel, new
            {
                htmlAttributes = new
                {
                    @min = "1",
                    @Value = "1",
                    @style = "width: 50px;",
                    title = testLevel_hint
                }
            })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.TestLevel)
    </div>
</div>
```

In the code `LocService` is a class I use for localization (all texts are localized). I'm not pasting it as I don't consider it relevant.

This next is the relevant `Resources.resx` fragment:

```
<data name="Test.TestLevel.Description" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Test Level (*)</value>
</data>
<data name="Test.TestLevel.Hint" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Test level will be shown in Test Me! app test selection screen.</value>
</data>
<data name="Test.TestLevel.Error1" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Test Level Cannot Be Blank.</value>
</data>
<data name="Test.TestLevel.Error2" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Only positive number allowed</value>
</data>
```

As you can see I have one text for the label, one for the html "title" and another for the validation message.

`TestViewModel`:

```
...
[Display(Name = "Test.TestLevel.Description", Description = "Test.TestLevel.Hint")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Test.TestLevel.Error1")]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Test.TestLevel.Error2")]
public int TestLevel { get; set; }
...
```

And my problem is that when I leave the test level field empty and try to save instead of showing the error message (resource key: `Test.TestLevel.Error1`) the ValidationMessageFor is showing the title message (resource key: `Test.TestLevel.Hint`), and I cannot figure out why.

The fact is that for other elements, like `Test Name`, it's working as expected (you can see it in the picture).

What can I try next?

[image: Test Admin Screenshot]

### Edit 1

I've noticed that if I remove the `title` property from the `htmlAttributes` section, then it works fine and displays the corresponding error message, but that's not the case as I wouldn't like to lose the title hint.

### Edit 2

I've just noticed that the wrong behavior happens only for `EditorFor` Razor helper, and not for `TextBoxFor`.

### Edit 3

This is how I configure localization service in `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LocService>();
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Localization");

builder.Services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
            return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
        };
    });

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
    options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US")
            };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());
    });
```

`LocService.cs`

```
public class LocService
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public LocService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(SharedResource);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public LocalizedString GetString(string key)
    {
        return _localizer[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Diego Perez, how do you configure the localization services in Program.cs?

Comment: Hi @Rena, thanks for replying. Please see my edited question, there you have the answer.